# Using perfectly formatted input as list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, input, list

I'm doing a program in Haskell (on the Haskell platform), and I know I'm getting perfectly formatted inputs, so the input may look like

```
[ ['a'], ['b'], ['c'] ]
```

I want Haskell to be able to take this and use it as a list of it's own. And, I'd like this list to be over multiple lines, i.e., I want this to also work:

```
[
  ['a'],
  ['b'],
  ['c']
]
```

I can parse this input, but I've been told there's a way to do this easily - this is supposed to be the 'trivial' part of the assignment, but I don't understand it.

Comment: Are you sure that the input is not `[ ['a'], ['b'], ['c'] ]` (i.e. comma-separated) because then it would be trivial (using `read`).

Comment: Sorry, I updated it, that's correct

Answer (score 9):

```
read "[ ['a'], ['b'], ['c'] ]" :: [[Char]]
```

will return `[ ['a'], ['b'], ['c'] ]`. If you assign the result of read to a variable that can be inferred to be of type `[[Char]]`, you don't need the `:: [[Char]]` bit.

Answer (score 3):

There is an instance of the [Read](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t%3ARead) class for Haskell lists, meaning you can use the [read](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Aread) function to effectively parse strings formatted like Haskell lists, which is exactly what you have.